# Decoupling a class that depends on another class whose constructor takes an argument

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, solid-principles

I have been practicing how to write clean code using SOLID. I have also been using DI in my code to remove coupling but only through constructor injection. In the many cases I have used DI, I have only used it to call methods. What I do not understand yet is how to decouple when you have a dependent class whose constructor takes an argument inside another class. If `var obj = new A(month)` creates dependency and tight coupling inside class B, how do I decouple/abstract this? Is this where the interface with property comes in? If so, how do I use it here?

```
public class A 
{
    private string _month;
    public A(string month) 
    {
        _month = month;
    }
}

public class B 
{
    public List<A> ListOfMonths;
    public B() 
    {
        ListOfMonths = new List<A>();
    }

    public List<A> SomeMethod() 
    {
        string[] months = new [] 
        {
            "Jan",
            "Feb",
            "Mar"
        };

        foreach(var month in months) 
        {
            var obj = new A(month); // If this is coupling, how do I remove it?
            ListOfMonths.Add(obj)
        }

        return ListOfMonths;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use a factory pattern.  Basically, inject an interface that can create objects of the correct type, so instead of `new AAA(month)` you can use `_AAAFactory.Create(month)`

Comment: What you're showing doesn't look like any sort of bad coupling and I'd question whether you should try to "fix" it. You don't need to introduce a factory. This *is* the factory.

Comment: @ScottHannen Are you arguing that `B` sort of acts as a factory of a list of `A`?

Comment: @StackLloyd - Not arguing. But in a sense, yes. Not that I'd call every class that creates and returns something a "factory." That would obscure the reasons why we use factories. But you could change the name of `B` to `AFactory` and change `SomeMethod` to `Create`. That's what it does.

Comment: @ScottHannen Uhm, yeah, to some extent, but in my opinion, since it returns a `List` of predefined objects (months), it doesn't really act as a factory. However, I agree that it doesn't look like a worrysome kind of tight coupling, since it simply instantiates some objects and gives them back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to decouple, you need to remove any reference to A from B and replace them by IA (interface similar to A) which is a placeholder for any class which would replace A.

In the constructor of B you then provide a factory able to create instances of IA. You go further by placing an abstract factory which means you provide an interface of a factory capable of creating instances of IA.

Here is a sample based on your code:

```
    public interface IA
    {
    }

    public interface IAFactory
    {
        IA BuildInstance(string month);
    }

    public class AFactory : IAFactory
    {
        public IA BuildInstance(string month)
        {
            return new A(month);
        }
    }

    public class A : IA
    {
        public A(string month)
        {
        }
    }

    public class B
    {
        private readonly IAFactory factory;
        public List<IA> ListOfMonths;

        public B(IAFactory factory)
        {
            this.factory = factory;
            ListOfMonths = new List<IA>();
        }

        public List<IA> SomeMethod()
        {
            string[] months = new[] {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar"};
            foreach (var month in months)
            {
                var obj = factory.BuildInstance(month);
                ListOfMonths.Add(obj);
            }

            return ListOfMonths;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR - There's no apparent coupling that you need to fix. Depending on abstractions is great, but it's possible to get carried away and add them where we don't need them. Create abstractions from the perspective of other classes that will depend on them *when you know you need them* so that you're always writing code you need, not code you don't need.

---

For your class to create instances of `A` is not bad coupling. Creating instances of `A` is the apparent purpose of `B`. `B` does not depend on `A` in the sense that it does not use it in any way. It just creates `A` and returns it because that's what it's supposed to do.

Another way of looking at it - how can a method that returns `A` not be coupled in some way to `A`? `B` doesn't need a factory. It *is* a factory.

There's also no apparent reason why you need an abstraction to represent `A`. If you needed to be able to mock `A` you could define an interface like `IA`. But nothing shown here indicates that you need that. It's so easy to create a "real" instance of `A` that there's no need to be able to mock it.

`var a = new A("February");`. What's to mock?

And if you did need an abstraction for `A` (like `IA`) then the only change immediately needed in `B` would be to change `SomeMethod` to return `List<IA>` instead of `List<A>`. Within that method you would create a `List<IA>` instead of `List<A>`, but you would still populate it with concrete instances of `A`.

The coupling this would remove (which, as I've emphasized, isn't shown in your code) would be with other classes, not shown, which currently depend on `A`, and depend on `B` to provide it. Now they would depend on `B` to provide `IA`, so *those other classes* would no longer be coupled to `A`.

Abstraction is great, but it can become a rabbit hole where we start adding interfaces and factories that we don't really need. (What happens when you're done replacing `A` with `IA`? Now you're coupled to `List<T>` - what to do about that?) If you can't test one class without also testing its dependencies, that's a good sign that the dependency must be an abstraction which you can mock.

If you can test everything - which in this case, you can - then introducing more abstraction is just creating work you don't need. That's not to say that I'd never start off with abstractions. In many cases it's pretty obvious that I'm going to need one. That's usually in cases where I'm going to do something with the dependency. In this case you're just returning it.

---

Here's a different way of looking at it: If you needed an abstraction, it would likely be an abstraction to *represent* `B`. If other classes, not shown here, needed instances of `A` or `IA` and the logic for creating them was slightly more complex, then *those* classes could depend on a factory, like

```
interface ISomethingFactory
{
    List<IA> Create();
}
```

`B` would be the *implementation* of that factory.

We should define abstractions from the point of view of the classes that depend on them. How will they interact with that dependency? Do I need to mock that dependency, and if so, how will I do that? When we look at classes as depending on (or *needing*) dependencies then we're writing code based on actual needs. That can prevent us from going down rabbit holes writing code we don't need (which I have done countless times.)

Comment: A very interesting point of view to ponder, especially about the use of `B`. Thank you for sharing your thoughts.

Comment: Very helpful explanation. I always thought that using the new keyword to create an object inside another class automatically creates coupling.

Comment: Using `new` to create dependencies creates coupling. We use dependency injection to inject dependencies rather than have the class create them. But these aren't dependencies. They're just the things that the method returns, just like the `List<T>`. You're creating that with `new` also, and that's also fine. You wouldn't introduce a "list factory" to avoid creating a new list.

Comment: Another way of describing it (this intrigues me because I understand how the explanation can be unclear.) An abstraction might make sense if you wanted `B` to be able to return something other than `A`. But if you want to return something other than `A`, you can just create a different class instead of modifying `B`. That's why the question shifts to the class that depends on `B`, not `B` itself. Instead of depending on `B`, they should depend on an abstraction that can be replaced or mocked. `B` would just be one implementation of it.

Answer (score 1):

One of the way to decouple `B` from `A` would be to define contract for `A`

```
interface IA { }
```

and implement it with `A`

```
public class A : IA {
 private string _month;
 public A(string month) {
  _month = month;
 }
}
```

Then from `B` replace all reference to `A` with `IA`

To resolve instantiation dependency factory could be used

```
public class AFactory {
 public IA CreateIA(string month) {
  return new A(month);
 }
}
```

The `AFavtory` could be instantiated with B when required (at `SomeMethod`)

Decoupling could be brought yet to another level with defining contract for the factory class

```
interface IAFactory {
 IA CreateIA(string month);
}
```

And implement this contract with `AFactory`.

After that The instance of `IAFactory` could be injected into `B` with
constructor

```
public B(IAFactory aFactory){
 _aFactory = aFactory;
 ...
}
```